# Show which "section" a blog article is posted under (on blog page and bulletin too)

Tags: feature-request, blog, community-bulletin

When a blog article appears in the 'community bulletin', there is no way to know which section the article is posted under. And when you click through to *read* the blog post, **the blog UI doesn't tell you** which section it is posted under either.

[image] [image]

**The Stack Overflow blog is broken up into five sections; each serves a different purpose.** I may be interested in posts about what the 'Company' is working on  (for example) but may have no interest in their 'Engineering'. Even when I'm *reading* an article, I don't have that context of what the post is about.

Both the blog post and the announcement should show which section the article is posted under.

Comment: We know the categories for the post when we pull it for the community bulletin... Fitting them into the display is a design challenge, though.

Comment: @AdamLear An extra word or before or after each title? `From Power Calculations to P-Values: A/B  Testing at Stack Overflow — Engineering`

Comment: Each post potentially has multiple categories. The one in the CB right now, for example, is both in Engineering and Insights.

Comment: @AdamLear looks like you need to reinvent tags.

Comment: @AdamLear I am assuming that's not the typical case, but it could look like this: `... A/B  Testing at Stack Overflow — Engineering, Insights`

Comment: Problem is, there are no sections, only tags. There are some "featured tags" in the blog which appear on top, but from everything I've seen, they're just ordinary tags. This is probably some limitation of WordPress? Not sure.